# how to check unbalanced brackets in python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x

How to check unbalanced brackets?
I am considering brackets --> `{`, `[`, `(`, `)`, `]`, `}`.
How can I check if a string is unbalanced?

Examples:

1. `{[()]}` --> Balanced
2. `{[(])}` --> Unbalanced
3. `{{[[(())]]}}` --> Balanced

I was trying this way, but it's not working:

```
string = '{[(])}'

par = 0
col = 0
cha = 0
for i in string:
    if i == '{':
        cha+=1
    if i == '}':
        cha-=1
    if i == '[':
        col+=1
    if i == ']':
        col-=1
    if i == '(':
        par+=1
    if i == ')':
        par-=1
    if (cha < 0) or (col < 0) or (par < 0):
        print('Unbalanced')
        break
if (cha != 0) or (col != 0) or (par != 0):
    print('Unbalanced')
else:
    print('Balanced')
```

Comment: Hint: what data structure allows you to remove only the most recently added element? What if you put your opening parentheses into this data structure?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't think you can verify the balancedness of a string just by keeping track of how many of each character you've seen so far. It matters what order you saw them in too, so you've got to incorporate that statefulness one way or the other. Here's one approach -- keep a stack of "unmatched" brackets. Add to it when you find a new left bracket, pop off of it when you find a right bracket that matches the most recent left bracket, and return False if you expect a match but don't get one. If you reach the end of the list and the stack is empty, then the string is balanced.

```
def balanced(s):
    pairs = {"{": "}", "(": ")", "[": "]"}
    stack = []
    for c in s:
        if c in "{[(":
            stack.append(c)
        elif stack and c == pairs[stack[-1]]:
            stack.pop()
        else:
            return False
    return len(stack) == 0


test_cases = ("{[()]}", "{[(])}", "{{[[(())]]}}")
for s in test_cases:
    print(s, balanced(s))
```

Result:

```
{[()]} True
{[(])} False
{{[[(())]]}} True
```

Comment: There's one more error case: if `stack[-1]` doesn't exist, that means the current closing bracket is unbalanced.

Comment: @wjandrea, good observation -- my original code would crash with IndexError on `balanced("]]]")`. Now that I've added an additional condition to my `elif`, it should handle this case properly.

Comment: This works but only for strings made up of only [({})] chars. It can easily be extended to handle any string with a mix of characters and brackets making it a lot more useful (IMHO).
The simple change would be to replace the `else: 
return` with `else :
continue`

Comment: @JohnT your way to extend would break the solution for cases like `]]]`. The condition to add is that, if there's a closing bracket without an opening bracket, it should return False

Comment: @luigi, yes, on reflection, where's no need to care about other chars if all you care about is 'balanced' or 'not balanced'.  Simply strip all other chars from the string before passing to the test function, in which case it works as in Kevin's updated code.

Answer (score 1):

You have to walk through the string and store the incoming chars. Every time the last two chars are `{}`, `[]`, `()`, just delete those chars and match the new char against the last stored (and not deleted). Continue until you reach the end of the string: if you deleted all chars, the string is balanced.

I find it easier to write with a fold:

```
>>> from functools import reduce
>>> def f(s): return reduce(lambda acc, x: acc[:-1] if acc and acc[-1]+x in ('{}', '[]', '()') else acc+x, s)
```

Tests cases:

```
>>> f('{[()]}')
'' # balanced
>>> f('{[(])}')
'{[(])}' # unbalanced
```

For a imperative version, see @Kevin's answer (the two branches of my if are equivalent to pop/push on the stack).

**EDIT** if you are looking for pseudo-palindrom (`{[]}` is balanced but not `{}[]`), you can match each char with the char at the same position beginning from the end.

First, check if the string has an even number of chars:

```
>>> s = '{[()]}'
>>> len(s) % 2
0
```

If that's the case, match the chars:

```
>>> t, u = s[:len(s)//2], s[len(s)//2:]
>>> t, u
('{[(', ')]}')
>>> t, "".join(reversed(u))
('{[(', '}])')
>>> [o+c for o,c in zip(t, reversed(u))]
['{}', '[]', '()']
```

The string is balanced iff you have only matching pairs:

```
>>> [o+c for o,c in zip(t, reversed(u)) if o+c not in ('{}', '[]', '()')]
[] # balanced
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a stack. Every time you encounter:

- a left parenthesis
- a left curly brace
- a left-bracket
- a left-anything

... push that left "delimiter" onto the stack. When you encounter a right-delimiter, pop the topmost element off the stack. The popped element will be the most recently seen left delimiter. Make sure that the left and right delimiters match. e.g. they are both parentheses, or both braces.

If the current left delimiter on the stack is a brace and the current right delimiter is a parenthesis, return the message that things are unbalanced.

If you ever try to pop something off an already empty stack, return "unbalanced."

If you read-in the entire string, but the stack isn't empty by the time you reach the end, return "unbalanced."

The above cover all of the cases in which the string is unbalanced.

If you read in the entire string and...

- the stack is empty when you are done
- you never tried to pop an empty stack
- the left delimiter on the stack always matched the right delimiter encountered (e.g. both were parentheses)

then the string is balanced. return "balanced"

Answer (score 1):

Here is an alternative code to check for unbalanced brackets:

```
def is_matched(expression):
    """
    Finds out how balanced an expression is.
    With a string containing only brackets.

    >>> is_matched('[]()()(((([])))')
    False
    >>> is_matched('[](){{{[]}}}')
    True
    """
    opening = tuple('({[')
    closing = tuple(')}]')
    mapping = dict(zip(opening, closing))
    queue = []

    for letter in expression:
        if letter in opening:
            queue.append(mapping[letter])
        elif letter in closing:
            if not queue or letter != queue.pop():
                return False
    return not queue

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import doctest
    doctest.testmod()
```

Answer (score 1):

I would just strip out balanced chunks of the string until I'm left with nothing or an unbalanced string that cannot be further reduced:

```
def is_matched(expr):
    expr = re.sub("[^][}{)(]+", "", expr)
    while expr:
        expr1 = re.sub(r"\(\)|\[\]|\{\}", "", expr)
        if expr1 == expr:
            return not expr1
        expr = expr1
    return True

>>> is_matched("{[()]}")
True
>>> is_matched("{[(])}")
False
>>> is_matched("{{[[(())]]}}")
True
```

The first `re.sub()` removed anything that isn't a parenthesis. The loop then removes all adjacent open/close pairs and repeats until we run out of string or we run out of adjacent pairs.

Answer (score 0):

If the first and last characters are a matched pair, peel them off.  Repeat.

If you ever get into a state where the first and last characters aren't a matched pair, the string was imbalanced.

EDIT: This won't work, as pointed out by @blhsing.

New approach: Look for `{}`, `[]`, or `()`, and remove it.  Repeat until no more are found.  If the string is empty, it was balanced, otherwise it wasn't.

Comment: This won't work for strings that contain multiple groups of matching pairs, e.g. `[]({})`.

Comment: Ah, you're right.  I should have known it wouldn't be that easy.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a stack based approach that converts the group characters to positive/negative numbers to make the rest of the logic independent of character processing (and allowing other characters in the string):

```
def isBalanced(s):
    opened = [0] # {}=3/-3, []=2/-2, ()=1/-1, others:0/-4
    for n in [3-("{[( )]}"+c).index(c) for c in s]:
        if not n&3 : continue
        elif n>0   : opened.append(n)
        elif opened.pop() != -n: return False
    return opened == [0]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def paranthesis(exprs):
    stack = []
    for char in exprs:
        if char in ["(","{","["]:
            stack.append(char)
        else:
            currchar = stack.pop()
            if currchar =="(":
                if char !=")":
                    return False
            if currchar == "{":
                if char != "}":
                    return False
            if currchar == "[":
                if char != "]":
                    return False
    if stack:
        print(stack)
        return False
    return True


if __name__ == "__main__":
    exprs = "({[]}]"

    if paranthesis:
        print("Balanced")
    else:
        print("Unbalanced")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty late to the game, but I expanded the solution given by @Kevin to consider also strings with letters, multiple closing brackets etc.

```
def BracketMatcher(strParam: str) -> bool:
  pairs = {'(':')', '[':']', '{':'}'}
  stack = []
  for c in strParam:
    if c in '([{':
      stack.append(c)
    elif c in ')]}':
      if not stack or c != pairs[stack[-1]]:
        return False
      stack.pop()
  return len(stack) == 0
```

Answer (score -2):

coming to @kevin 's answer. The following passes all his test cases but it is simpler.

```
def balanced(s):
    if s.count('[') == s.count(']') and s.count('(') == s.count(')') and s.count('{') == s.count('}'):
        return True
    else:   
        return False
```

The goal to ask such a question is not just to see the count but whether the brackets as a whole make sense. If it is asked in an interview you would like to let them know that you understand the motive behind it.

```
Prob_test_cases = ('}{', '][', ')(')
```

Most solutions will pass the above as balanced or parenthesis match but ideally they should fail.
You do not encode your code or string like that in `Prob_test_cases`. Here is what I have.
long but understandable without any stack, queue or data structure implementation.

```
def para_check(checkme):
    open = ['(', '[', '{']
    close = [')', ']', '}']
    # assume that the result is true
    result = True

    # if the input is not a list then convert it to list
    if type(checkme) is not list:
        checkme = list(checkme)

    # if it doesnt contain at least 2 elements then return false
    if len(checkme) < 2:
        result = False

    # if number of closing and opening paranthesis is not the same then it is not balanced
    count_check1 = checkme.count('[') == checkme.count(']')
    count_check2 = checkme.count('(') == checkme.count(')')
    count_check3 = checkme.count('{') == checkme.count('}')

    # if not all of the above are true then it is unbalanced and thus...
    if not all([count_check1, count_check2, count_check3]):
        result = False

    def recurser(checkme, first, last):
        '''
        here start can be '[,(,{' and end can be '],),}' respectively,
        Check for a given type of bracket (any 1 of 3) see if the 
        index of the first closing bracket is greater than the first 
        opening bracket and if yes then remove them since they are a pair.
        Repeat this forever for all 3 types of brackets.
        '''            
        if first in checkme and last in checkme:
            open_index = checkme.index(first)
            closed_index = checkme.index(last)
            
            if closed_index > open_index:
                checkme.pop(closed_index)
                checkme.pop(open_index)
                # recursion
                recurser(checkme, first, last)
            else:
                result = False

    recurser(checkme, '[', ']')
    recurser(checkme, '(', ')')
    recurser(checkme, '{', '}')

    if len(checkme) > 0:
        result = False

    return result
```

Comment: Your first claim about the accepted answer doesn't make sense. The answerer can't put all the test cases to prove that it works. And I really can't see the point in your answer. A `stack`or `queue` in other answers are just Python `list`s. So you don't need to implement anything additional for them.

Comment: @Asocia I agree that stack or queue are lists but the only difference being how you push or pop the items in it. The first part of the answer does not even make use
`stack or
queue or
insert or
pop`. This is one of the interview questions and usually when you achieve the first part (check the count) then they ask you to implement the 2nd part, whether they are properly closing or not (prob_test_cases) coz I have been through this. Also those who are asking such questions are usually beginners. We should keep it as simple as possible which requires least number of pieces to understand.

Comment: @Asocia A beginner's question needs a beginner friendly answer which puts least burden on them to understand or grasp all pieces of the solution. My answer requires the person to know only how the `list.count()` works. The chosen answer expects the beginner to know
LIFO (stack), FIFO(queue) and dictionary.

Comment: Your solution requires knowing more than `list.count()`. It uses a recursive function that is considered to be hard to understand by default because of its nature. Our brains can follow a procedural code easier than a recursive alternative. Of course this doesn't mean that we shouldn't use recursive functions. Sometimes they just outperforms any other non-recursive solution. But it's not the case for this question, *I think*.

Comment: And the accepted answer doesn't mention about LIFO, FIFO or expects from OP to know about them. It's just saying that *"keep a stack of something"*. The name "stack" could be anything ("collection", "list", "container"...) but "stack" is chosen because this is the name of the data structure that people might know from other languages so they can understand the algorithm easier.

Comment: @Asocia stack is LIFO, queue is FIFO when you provide a solution involving any of these, you are assuming that the person knows this or has to learn them first to know the solution.
Here I was comparing `balanced(s)' with the chosen answer. In the `balanced(s)` there is no recursion, there is no stack, there is no queue, there is no dictionary.
Yes. 2nd part of my answer does include recursion but then again adds only one element.

Comment: Are you aware that "stack" is a valid English word and can be used in daily life? So OP doesn't have to know what stack is to understand the answer. You keep emphasizing that your answer doesn't use stack, queue, dictionary. If you really want to compare there you go:

Comment: Accepted answer only uses a `list` and giving it a name `stack`. It solves the problem in an efficient way because iterating through every item just once. It does use a `dict` but it is not hard to learn if the OP don't know it. Your solution introduces a bad coding practice by repeating itself. Just think how many lines you need change if one more pair is added (i.e `<` and `>`) and compare it with the accepted answer. You have a recursive function. Which one would be harder to understand: a simple dictionary or a recursive function that consists of 10 lines?

Comment: I just realized something. Are you **really** comparing your first function, `balanced` with the accepted one and claiming that it's *better* because it's simpler and still passes all the tests? I think we can stop the discussion at this point. Thanks.

Comment: @Asocia yes and no. When it comes to test cases yes, When it comes to full solution or the motto behind an interviewer asking such question, then no.

Comment: Your first function doesn't take into account cases like `[{]}` which should return `False`, instead your function returns `True` since it just counts the occurences of each bracket